# How does the Catholic Church explain the term “the Son”: in the Sign of the Cross as well as in Matthew 28:19?

Tags: catholicism, trinity, gospel-of-matthew, sign-of-the-cross

We read at Mtt 28:19:

> Go therefore and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit.

In the Sign of the Cross we  take the name of the Father, of the Son and of the Holy Spirit in that order.

Jn 1:14 also says: "And the Word became flesh and lived among us, and we have seen his glory, the glory as of a father’s only son, full of grace and truth.”

That implies that the Son we refer to in the Sign of the Cross is the pre-incarnation person of the Trinity. If it meant Jesus, his name  would have to be preceded  by Holy Spirit by whose power he was born of Virgin Mary. My question therefore, is: **How does the Catholic Church explain the term “the Son” in the Sign of the Cross as well as in Mathew 28:19?**

Comment: Is not the Son (the pre-incarnation person of the Trinity to whom you refer) the same person as Jesus Christ, come in the flesh ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no contradiction.

Jesus is Incarnate God who is "the Word with God" in the beginning (John 1:1); He is the 2nd Person (The Son) of the Holy Trinity.

> If it meant Jesus, his name would have to be preceded by Holy Spirit by whose power he was born of Virgin Mary.

No. The Name of Jesus (or the Son or the Word) insofar as He is God precedes the Name of the Holy Spirit (the Holy Spirit proceeds from the Father and the Son). The Incarnation doesn't alter the relations of the Divine Persons. The Sign of the Cross and the baptismal formula are Trinitarian invocations -- they reflect the unaltered relations of the Divine Persons, not the incarnation of the Word.

Comment: That the Holy Spirit 'proceeds from' the Father is surely not a matter of 'preceding' (in time) in regard to Divine Relationship. Do you mean that the incarnation (of Jesus) precedes the gift of anointing (of the Holy Spirit) ?

Comment: I think I was referring to the ordering of the names, given OP assumed that if the Son refers to Jesus, it should be preceded by the Holy Spirit